# How to select new object set property = other property value

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not good at English, I have difficulty in title setting. And also so I do not know the keyword to be able to find what I need.

I want the following:

```
var newList = listUsers.Select(x => new { x.Name = x.Old});
```

But I get an error like this:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
>   be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

**Note: I do not want the following**

```
var newList = listUsers.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Old = x.Old});
```

**Update**: My final goal would be to output the format like this:

```
var arr = [{
            John Doe: 19,
            David: 23,
            David: 26
        }, {

            John Doe: 27,
            David: 22,
            David: 24
        }];
```

where the user name list is dynamic

Comment: Well, can you explain what do you want? If you want new object you can use `Anonymous type` or some similar class, if you want to assign a new value you can do it with `foreach`

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `x` from the first of the Anonymous type members's name:

```
var newList = listUsers.Select(x => new { Name = x.NameNew});
```

Or if you want to update all `Name` property with `NameNew` you need the `return x;` also like this (don't use the `new` keyword in this case):

```
var newList = listUsers.Select(x => { x.Name = x.NameNew;return x; });
```

Comment: I want set `value Name = x.NewName`
Ex: `Jonh Doe = "New Name"`

Comment: @TranAudi Well this will set the `Name = New Name`. What's problem?

Comment: @TranAudi This will create an *Anonymous type* with a property called `Name` that it's value is `x.NameNew`.

Comment: @TranAudi Check my updated answer. It is another approach. And I think this is what you want.

Comment: Hi.
It seems I'm misinterpreted, you misunderstand, I've updated my question, please review and help me, thanks

Comment: @TranAudi I think you didn't notice my last update and didn't notice to the `return x` part. This is exactly what you need based on your question and your comments. Also your final goal that you updated your question is completely a different requirement and should be asked in a new question with different title.

Comment: I have solved this problem in javascript, in a loop, I created star constellation, and it will be added to an array.
Thanks for help