# @HTML.Grid LINQ using if condition in HTML itself

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I have a Grid like this:

```
 @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Add(c => c.resolved).Titled("Resolved").Filterable(false);
}
```

All I want to do is to modify the `c.resolved` default value `0` to the text `No`.

My question is: Is it possible to modify it in HTML itself without doing anything in the Controller?

I am thinking about something like:

```
columns.Add(c => if(c.resolved==0{c.resolved=='No';})).Titled("Resolved").Filterable(false);
```

Comment: The LINQ equivalent would be: `columns.Add(c => c.resolved == 0 ? "No" : c.resolved.ToString()).Titled("Resolved").Filterable(false);`. It uses the [Ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). The `ToString()` is to ensure that the result is a string.

Comment: You might need to use `return` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042841/2946329 and also ternary operator.

Comment: Thanks @TernaryOperator but it return me an error `Expression 'c => IIF((c.resolved == "0"), "No", c.resolved)' not supported by grid`

Comment: Thanks @S.Akbari but no luck.

Comment: Sorry its @KeyurPATEL not TernaryOperator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `RenderValueAs`;

```
columns.Add().Titled("Resolved").Filterable(false)
           .RenderValueAs(o => o.resolved == 0 ? "No" : o.resolved.ToString());
```